# how to spawn multiple instances of web api in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, port

I'm trying to implement a basic load balancing only on the instances level which means that all the instances are hosted in the same server, however every time I start a second instance of my api I always encounter an error indicating that the current port is already in use by the first instance.
first how to make my api uses a different port if the default one is already in use and secondly I'm wondering if there are any benefits from adding load balancing at the instance level, I don't want the ports to be random because I need to know these ports in order to configure nginx for load balancing so I don't have to change the config file each time an instance is terminated.

I've tried to add these ports in the launchsettings.json file but now each instance is listening to all ports I've added

Comment: `all the instances are hosted in the same server` <= this is not the purpose of load balancing. A well designed application can be load balanced across servers. If you find your application responds better with multiple instances on the same server then the application code should be refactored or analyzed for performance problems. Alternatively maybe you have the application instance being limited by configuration settings and it can't use as many resources as it needs to function correctly.

Comment: hi thanks for your replay, currently the purpose of adding load balancing is to serve as a backup in case of the api shuts down for some reason, is there any approach you would suggest in this stuation. @Igor

Comment: Why would the API shut down? If this does or can happen you need to figure out why and fix that problem. Load balancing is used for planned resource distribution or instance failover where a entire server instance becomes unavailable or unstable. If the API itself becomes unstable or unavailable but the server instance is OK then there is a defect in the code or a defect in the configuration that needs to be addressed.